# Can't perform sendKeys method in angular webapp

Tags: java, html, angular, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I'm working on creating an automation test bed for my job and I'm running into an issue where I can't access and send through a method with how their html is written.

```
<div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c183-3">
 <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c183-3">
  <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c183-3">

   <input _ngcontent-ibj-c243="" maxlength="800" matinput="" 
   formcontrolname="filterValue" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field- 
   autofill-control ng-tns-c183-3 ng-pristine ng-valid cdk-text-field- 
   autofill-monitored ng-touched" ng-reflect-name="filterValue" ng-reflect- 
   maxlength="800" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria- 
   required="false">

  <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c183-3"><label 
  class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c183-3 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty 
  ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-3" 
  ng-reflect-ng-switch="true" for="mat-input-0" aria-owns="mat-input-0"> 
  <mat-label _ngcontent-ibj-c243="" class="ng-tns-c183-3 ng-star- 
  inserted">Search</mat-label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--></label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></span></div></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c183-3 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c183-3"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c183-3" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c183-3 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c183-3"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}-->
</div>
</div>
```

[image: image of input wrapped]
This is the input that I'm trying to access with the method.

I'm attempting to pass through a regular set of alphanumerics so that I can perform a search using the search bar.

These are all of the methods I've tried.

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search-field\"]")).sendKeys("1000000");
//driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-0")).sendKeys("1000000");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c183-3 ng-pristine ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched']")).sendKeys("1000045949");
//driver.findElement(By.class("mat-input-element")).sendKeys("1000000);
```

```
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 111, so returning the closest version found: 110
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#mat\-input\-0"}
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.147)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [ac239ea7458d50777e81aa5e2d1214ba, findElement {using=id, value=mat-input-0}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 111.0.5563.147, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ne1723\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:62610}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:62610/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 111.0.5563.147, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: ac239ea7458d50777e81aa5e2d1214ba
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at fgi.fgiCreateCode.main(fgiCreateCode.java:35)
```

```
package fgi;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class fgiCreateCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "xxx");

        ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        //Launching the browser
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("xxx");


        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);

        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xxx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search-field\"]")).sendKeys("xxx");
        //driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-0")).sendKeys("xxx");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c183-3 ng-pristine ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched']")).sendKeys("xxx");


        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that all you need here is a webdriverwait...  try/catch your "driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-0")).sendKeys("1000000");" call to see what exception is thrown and add it to your post.

Comment: angular front-ends are very active, so adding some of the code you have before this call to your post would be helpful too.  (for instance, it'll change styles from pristine, to touched, to dirty, etc... ex: 'ng-touched' class has been added to the element you posted)

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the initial information. I've added the code that that is above the /input and added the error msg I receive when I run the test.

Comment: you can see by the exception that the selector is wrong... it's showing "#mat\-input\-0".  Post your Selenium code with some of the lines before you try to find that element.

Comment: @pcalkins upated

Comment: I would use: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-0']")).sendKeys("xxx");  (But you should add webdriverwaits to all these calls:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ ) You'll be able to remove all those sleeps too.

Comment: also, do not do this: driver.switchTo().frame(0); (unnecessary)

Comment: @pcalkins thanks ill check it out and see if it works. Also I need that piece of code to get past the iframe for the login page otherwise i wont be able to log in.

Comment: ahh... gotcha.  You can also use a webdriverwait for that with expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(int)  It'll both wait until it's ready and switch the driver to that frame.

Comment: @pcalkins wanted to thank you again for the help over the last two days. I'm confused as well about how to use waits and expected conditions but its better than nothing. I wanted to ask if you do any tutoring or would be interested in it? I'm willing to pay. I don't want the answers, I want to understand what needs to be done and how its happening.

Comment: I don't.  I can say that when I want to learning something I read a lot.  If you feel you need more than the tutorial at selenium.dev (and I don't blame you, it's not the best documentation), buy a book on Java and Selenium and read through that.  Once you're done reading just go about your task and things will start to click as you get things done and the grokking begins!  (it also helps if you have a good grasp on HTML, Javascript and some server-side language too...)

Comment: You might also find my hobby project useful while learning:  https://www.browsermator.com